# Remove columns with only NA values with SparkR

Tags: r, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, sparkr

I am using SparkR in databricks to manipulate large dataframes. I have a spark DataFrame `df` from which I want to remove all the columns containing only `NA` values. In typical R I would use either the tidyverse approach

```
df %>% select_if(~any(!is.na(.)))
```

or in base R

```
df[!sapply(df, function(x) all(is.na(x)))]
```

However, none of those two methods seem to work in SparkR. I also want to use as much as possible the capabilities of Spark to distribute the work. I have found the following solution

```
nacols<- sapply(columns(df), function(c){
  nbna <- SparkR::select(df, c) %>% SparkR::na.omit() %>% SparkR::nrow()
  return(nbna != 0)
})

df_nona<- df %>% SparkR::select(columns(df)[c(T, nacols)])
```

but I think it is inefficient considering SparkR does not distribute the work of `sapply`.

Please let me know if you can think of a better way to do so. I am open to doing this part of my script in python as well using pyspark. However, as I am using a high concurrency cluster, I cannot use scala code.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to drop the columns containing only NAs with the following code :

```
library(SparkR)

df <- data.frame(V1 = base::sample(1 : 10,5),
                 V2 = base::rep(NA,5), 
                 V3 = base::sample(1 : 10,5),
                 V4 = base::rep(NA,5), 
                 V5 = base::rep(NA,5), 
                 X = runif(n = 5, min = 0, max = 5))

sdf <- createDataFrame(df)
col_Names <- colnames(sdf)
nb_Col_Names <- length(col_Names)
vec_Bool <- rep(FALSE, nb_Col_Names)
 
for(i in 1 : nb_Col_Names)
{ 
  dim_Temp <- dim(dropna(select(sdf, col = col_Names[i]), how = "all"))
  if(dim_Temp[1] != 0) vec_Bool[i] <- TRUE
}
 
col <- col_Names[vec_Bool]
newdf <- select(sdf, col = col)
as.data.frame(newdf)

V1 V3        X
1  6  1 2.286716
2 10  3 3.532843
3  2  9 2.030851
4  8  6 3.304420
5  4 10 1.596272
```