# How to drop all NA columns in a SparkDataFrame with SparkR?

Tags: r, azure, databricks, sparkr

Once again, I'm facing a problem that I can't transcribe under `SparkR`.
I have a SparkDataFrame which some columns contain only NAs, and I want to delete all these columns.

I discovered SparkR recently, I think I'm far from understanding all its operation, but it's very frustrating to block on a point yet not so complicated...

Here is the reprex and the way I am doing it in R :

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(V1 = base::sample(1:10,5), V2 = base::rep(NA,5), V3 = base::sample(1:10,5), V4 = base::rep(NA,5), V5 = base::rep(NA,5), X = runif(n = 5, min = 0, max = 5))
sdf <- createDataFrame(df)
dt <- setDT(df)

na.lst <- sapply(dt, function(x) all(is.na(x)))
dt[, which(na.lst) := NULL]
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach

```
library(SparkR)

df <- data.frame(V1 = base::sample(1 : 10,5),
                 V2 = base::rep(NA,5), 
                 V3 = base::sample(1 : 10,5),
                 V4 = base::rep(NA,5), 
                 V5 = base::rep(NA,5), 
                 X = runif(n = 5, min = 0, max = 5))

sdf <- createDataFrame(df)
col_Names <- colnames(sdf)
nb_Col_Names <- length(col_Names)
vec_Bool <- rep(FALSE, nb_Col_Names)
 
for(i in 1 : nb_Col_Names)
{ 
  dim_Temp <- dim(dropna(select(sdf, col = col_Names[i]), how = "all"))
  if(dim_Temp[1] != 0) vec_Bool[i] <- TRUE
}
 
col <- col_Names[vec_Bool]
newdf <- select(sdf, col = col)
as.data.frame(newdf)

V1 V3        X
1  6  1 2.286716
2 10  3 3.532843
3  2  9 2.030851
4  8  6 3.304420
5  4 10 1.596272
```

See [Remove columns with only NA values with SparkR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57912248/remove-columns-with-only-na-values-with-sparkr/73936299#73936299)